# Hi i get this "Error Call to a member function update() on boolean" when updating image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone help me with this Laravel problem?

I get `Error Call to a member function update() on boolean`, when I edit and update Image for an ad.

So when I create a new Ad the image will store but when updating the Ad with a new image the old image stays and I get this error for this line in `storeImage`.

```
private function storeImage($ad){

    if (request()->has('image')) {
        $ad->update([
            'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public'),
        ]);

        $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/' . $ad->image))->fit(300, 300, null, 'top-left');
        $image->save();

    }
}
```

This is my **AdsController**

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $ad = Ad::find($id);

   return view('ads.edit_ad', compact('ad', 'id'));
}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $ad = Ad::find($id);

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $rules = [
    'ad_title'  => 'required',
    'ad_description'  => 'required',
    'purpose'  => 'required',
    'image'  => 'sometimes|file|image|max:5000',
    ];


    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $title = $request->ad_title;


    $is_negotialble = $request->negotiable ? $request->negotiable : 0;

    $data = [
    'title'         => $request->ad_title,
    'description'   => $request->ad_description,
    'type'          => $request->type,
    'price'         => $request->price,
    'purpose'       => $request->purpose,
    'address'       => $request->address,
    'user_id'       => $user_id,
    ];


    $updated_ad = $ad->update($data);

    if ($updated_ad){
        $this->storeImage($updated_ad);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Ad Updated');
}


public function destroy(Ad $ad)
{

    $ad->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Ad Deleted');
}


/**
* Listing
*/

public function listing(Request $request){

    $ads = Ad::all();

    $roles = Role::all();

    return view('listing', compact('ads'));
}

public function myAds(){

    $user = Auth::user();
    $ads = $user->ads()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);

    return view('ads.my_ads', compact('ads'));
}

private function storeImage($ad){

    if (request()->has('image')) {
        $ad->update([
        'image' => request()->image->store('uploads', 'public'),
        ]);

        $image = Image::make(public_path('storage/' . $ad->image))->fit(300, 300, null, 'top-left');
        $image->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: its because your `$ad` in  `storeImage()` is a boolean value! `update` is called in a model  object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the bottom of your update() function, try to change this:

```php
if ($updated_ad){
    $this->storeImage($updated_ad);
}
```

to this:

```php
if ($updated_ad){
    $this->storeImage($ad);
}
```

The Eloquent models `update()` function returns a boolean of whether the update completed successfully. After running the `update()` function on the `$ad` variable, it is mutated and contains the updated data, and you can use it as an argument in your `storeImage()` function.

Comment: I see what i’ve done wrong. The explanation is clear. Thanks man!